# Python Import argv error

Tags: python, pyscripter

Trying to get this to run in Pyscripter, and getting the following error:

```
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
```

I am quite new to coding with Python and Pyscripter so if you could explain why your answer works, that would be great. Thanks

```
from sys import argv

script, user_name = argv
prompt = '>'

print "Hi %s, I'm the %s script." %(user_name, script)
print "I'd like to ask you a few questions."
print "Do you like me %s?" %user_name
likes = raw_input(prompt)

print "Where do you live %s?" %user_name
lives = raw_input(prompt)

print "What kind of computer do you have?"
computer = raw_input(prompt)

print """
Alright, so you said %r about liking me.
You live in %r. Not sure where that is.
And you have a %r computer. Nice.
""" %(likes, lives, computer)
```

Comment: You may want to use the `argparse` module instead of `sys.argv`.

Comment: How are you running the script? You should be running it with one argument.

Comment: Argparse is a much better way to do exactly what you want to do: https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html

Comment: Also, next time, provide the full backtrace. Now we see an error quoted without context.

Comment: Argparse is not appropriate for the skill level and goals that OP is trying to accomplish.  Let's focus on just helping him get past this challenge.

Answer (score 3):

In this snippet of code: `script, user_name = argv`, "`argv`" is the command line args.  If it's fewer than two arguments, you get that error because python cannot decompose `argv` into `script` and `user_name`.

So you should either handle this error case and/or provide more arguments when you call the script.

You can reproduce this problem at the interactive python prompt like so:

```
>>> from sys import argv
>>> argv
['']
>>> a, b = argv
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack
>>> argv_new = ['some', 'argument', 'list',]
>>> a, b = argv_new
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: too many values to unpack
>>> a, b, c = argv_new
>>> a
'some'
>>> b
'argument'
>>> c
'list'
```

Answer (score 0):

`argv` is already a `list` so you can't unpack it like you are trying to do here if you supplied the wrong number of arguments on the command line. It appears this is what you did here hence the error you got.

Say your goal is to extract the script and the first argument only you could do this:

```
from sys import argv

script = argv[0]
user_name = argv[1]
```

Note that the name of the script is stored as the first element of the list, all the other arguments are then found after that. This will work provided you have more than one command line argument.

If you want to make sure that there's only one argument then you can check the length of the `argv` list with `len(sys.argv)`.

```
from sys import argv

if len(argv) == 2:
    script = argv[0]
    user_name = argv[1]
else:
    print("Bad number of arguments supplied on command line")
    exit()
```

However if we are testing that we have the right number of command line arguments we can then safely use the unpacking syntax like this:

```
if len(argv) == 2:
    script, user_name = argv #works because argv is the correct length
else:
    print("Bad number of arguments supplied on command line")
    exit()
```

The more advanced way to do this would however be to use [Argparse](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/argparse.html) so you might want to look into that when you are more comfortable with Python.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are not passing the required argument to argv. From pydoc sys:

> argv -- command line arguments; argv[0] is the script pathname if
>   known

As per learnpythonthehardway.org, where this example code is from.. When you run this, remember that you have to give the script your name for the argv arguments.

IE:

> ./ex14.py MyName